# Flask-WTForm combination is receiving data (request.form), but is not saving in RegistrationForm()

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to make a simple web app where I can upload data from a client to a database, and then send it back. I have everything done except the user authentication and session handling. I am new to Flask-WTForms (and flask tbh), and my example code is below. My problem is that when I try I cannot retrieve my form data through the WTForm that I made. I can only get data from request.form. However that is not ideal because I am trying to use Flask-login.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    USERS = mongo.db.users
    u = USERS.find_one({"username": username})
    if not u:
       return None
    return User(u['username'])

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    USERS = mongo.db.users
    myform = RegistrationForm()
    if myform.validate_on_submit():
        USERS.insert({"Username": myform.username.data, "Password": 
myform.password.data})
        return "REGISTERED"
    print(request.form["Username"])
    return "ERROR: Your request failed"
```

When I try to get data through WTForms it does not work and fails, but request.form has the data. I know that flask_wtf does not require it, but I also tried:

```
myform = RegistrationForm(request.form)
```

For completeness sake, here is my form file as well.

```
  from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, validators
  from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
  from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Side note, I know Sql is easier for this project, but I am using mongo for other reasons.

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you mean when you say "[it] is not ideal [to use request.form] because I am trying to use Flask-login"?

Comment: using WTForm forms (RegistrationForm()) lets me do authentication and save users in a much easier fashion

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when I try I cannot retrieve my form data through the WTForm that I made. I can only get data from request.form.

My understanding is that accessing `request.form` *is* in fact the way that you are supposed to retrieve your form data.

First, some issues I spotted:

- In `load_user()`, you write `return User(u['username'])`, which would appear to be returning a totally new `User` object rather than an ORM-created object which represents the actual record in the database. The problem with this is that it won't have any extra data that's in the database; it'll just be a User object with the name set to `u['username']`.
- In `register()`, you are attempting to insert new users into the database without first checking whether the specified name already exists.

I just set up signup and login for my Flask app and it was a hassle, so I'll try to save you some time by showing you the code I ended up with. I have these in separate files, but you can also have them all in one file. Separating them out into separate files actually added another layer of complication involving blueprints and creating the model files the right way.

`routes.py`:

```
(...)

web_routes = Blueprint('web_routes', __name__)

(...)

@web_routes.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first():
                return "Email address already exists"
            else:
                new_user = User(form.email.data, form.password.data)
                db.session.add(new_user)
                db.session.commit()

                login_user(new_user)

                return redirect(url_for('web_routes.pay'))
        else:
            return "Form didn't validate"


@web_routes.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():

    form = SignupForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
            if user:
                if user.check_password(form.password.data):
                    login_user(user)
                    return redirect(url_for('web_routes.app'))
                else:
                    return "Wrong password"
            else:
                return "user doesn't exist"
    else:
        return "form not validated"
```

`forms.py`:

```
(...)

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired()])


class SignupForm(Form):
    email = StringField('email')
    password = PasswordField('password')
    submit = SubmitField("Sign In")
```

`models.py`:

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, \
     check_password_hash

(...)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(200))

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.set_password(password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.email

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.email)


def init_db():
    db.create_all()

    # Create a test user
    new_user = User('a@a.com', 'aaaaaaaa')
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
```

`app.py`:

```
(...)

from flask_login import LoginManager
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
    from models import User
    return User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from routes import web_routes
    app.register_blueprint(web_routes)

    # To get PyCharm's debugger to work, you need to have "debug=False, threaded=True"
    #app.run(debug=False, threaded=True)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try adding form process method below the form instantiated, e.g.

USERS = mongo.db.users
myform = RegistrationForm()  # This's your form instantiated
myform.process(formdata=None, obj=USERS = mongo.db.users)  # Add this
```

I'm don't know about mongo-db but assuming that USERS it's an object containing the data searched.

This work form me